# Qt Application Random Crashes via using callbacks and emitting signals from std::thread or boost::thread

Tags: c++, qt

I have an annoying issue with Qt and multi threading. Below I have created some simplified code. In my real code, the principle is exactlty the same but way too complex hence for using a simplified version.

The problem is that the application randomly crashes during different points at the run-time with different messages:

```
free(): invalid pointer
double free or corruption
```

The crash is triggered from within Qt, I will explain at the end of the post.

Here is how the code works.

So, I have **classA** that starts a thread:

```
class classA
{
   public:

      void                                   start();
      boost::function<void (std::string)>    __ptr; // for callback

   private:

      boost::thread  *                    thread;
      void                                run();
};

void classA:start()
{ 
   thread = new boost::thread(&classA::run, this); // start the thread
}
```

and here is the actual method that runs in the separate thread:

```
void classA::run()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
   {
      static int count = 0;

      __ptr("test123" + std::to_string(++count));
   }
}
```

In my `QDialog` inherited class, I have a simple method that assigns the `boot::function` so I have declared another `boost::function` ptr. The problem is not with the ptr, it is with Qt, read on, the call back works just fine...

```
class myClassB : public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public:

      explicit myClassB (QWidget *parent);
      classA   ca;

   private:

      boost::function<void (std::string)>    __ptr;

      void mycallback(std::string);   
};
```

In the constructor of **myClassB**, I am assigning my call back to `boost::function` like this (like I said, the callback works fine).

```
myClassB::myClassB()
{
   this->__ptr    = ( boost::bind( &myClassB::mycallback, this, _1 ) );
   ca.__ptr       = __ptr;   
}
```

Here is where the problem starts. In my callback within my classB QDialog, I emit a Qt signal

```
void myClassB::mycallback(std::string txt)
{
   emit sig_qt_data_received(txt);   
}
```

This signal gets connected in my classB's constructor:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(sig_qt_data_received(std::string)), this, SLOT(data_received(std::string)), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

and finally, the implementation of the Qt slot:

```
void myclassB::data_received(std::string txt)
{
    ui->lbl_status->setText(txt);
}
```

**This is where the problem is:**

**If you remove** `ui->lbl_status->setText(txt);`, the program works flawlessly, it never crashes, if you leave it, it randomly crashes:

```
free(): invalid pointer
double free or corruption
```

It appears that the problem is within Qt as when I remove the setText() references, it does *not* crash and I have followed just about every GUI multi-threading procedure I have found and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

To connect the Qt signal, I am using `Qt::DirectConnection` and if I use `Qt::AutoConnection` it will work without a crash <s>but sometimes the whole UI freezes</s> (Edit: **this is incorrect, see my answer**).

I hope someone can help. If you need more code / real code, let me know, I will write an actual runnable code that you can run and compile but the fundamentals are the same, that's how the code works.

I don't want to be using QThread.

Comment: There's a lot of code/context missing from your question but... the fact that explicitly specifying the connection type as `Qt::DirectConnection` changes the behaviour suggests you've almost certainly got a race condition due to threading.  Note, also, that there shouldn't be any need to allocate a `boost::thread` using `new` as it's move constructible/assignable.

Comment: G.M, if you post an answer, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved! `Qt::DirectConnection` was the culprit, now I use `Qt::AutoConnection` and it never crashes and according to the docs it is the default:

> (Default) If the receiver lives in the thread that emits the signal,
>   Qt::DirectConnection is used. Otherwise, Qt::QueuedConnection is used.
>   The connection type is determined when the signal is emitted.

G.M's response above gave me the hint (Thanks):

> the fact that explicitly specifying the connection type as
>   Qt::DirectConnection changes the behaviour suggests you've almost
>   certainly got a race condition due to threading

Also thank you jpo38 for suggesting / replying anyway.

Now I know I said sometimes it would freeze but no, **that's incorrect**, it never freezes, I had confused things.